# Executing bash script from php not working on Windows

Tags: php, windows, bash, xampp, wampserver

I have executed this script under xampp ( ubuntu ) it works fine. but when i tried to execute it under windows it gives me no error but also no output.

`<?
$command='ls -l';
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>`

PHP do not run in save mode. what is the problem ? is it depending on the OS ?

Comment: In short, yes. There are Bourne Shell implementations available for Windows (so that you'll be able to run bash scripts). http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because *ls* is unix based command and is not available on Windows

Not showing errors is because shell_exec only outputs STDOUT and not STDERR, if you want to be able to view error you can run your command like this:

```
$output = shell_exec("{$command} 2>&1");
```

which will show an error stating that ls was not found or something similar

in windows instead of *ls* you can run *dir*

this might help:

```
<?
    $command=substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)=='WIN'?'dir':'ls -l';
    $output = shell_exec("{$command} 2>&1");
    echo $output;
?>
```